# What is Soraka's best role after her Patch 4.17 Rework?

Tags: league-of-legends

As you all know, Soraka recently received a gameplay update with new abilities with some similarities to her old abilities. What have her ability changes pushed her towards, mid lane or support?

Comment: This suggest more a "What's your opinion" or "Primary opinion answer's". So I'm voting to close the question. If you comes up with something more specific it'll be better.

Comment: Like "I usually play with *this kind of strategy* but now, after the changes I find difficulty to do it. What can I do about? should I switch roles so I could keep playing Soraka"?

Comment: surely using the word 'should' makes it more opinion based?

Comment: @Michel Meta-Gameplay Question ;) I'd say you can count this as a strategy question in LoL.

Comment: This isn't a question to be closed, in fact, answer would be about the possibilities with Soraka and it's good to know. However you should clarify the patch version on which soraka has been changed.

Comment: @Fabián No, patch information should not be included.  By doing so, you're artificially limiting the utility of the question to only a single aspect of the game.  Questions are supposed to withstand the test of time, and by narrowing it to only a specific point in time is moot for LoL, as there's no way to play previous patches.

Comment: @Frank I think he meant to provide informations about the patch that did the rework, not to limit it to a certain patch. Since this champion has already recieved a rework in an earlier patch it's not entirely clear about which rework we're talking here. I'll edit it to clarify.

Comment: @Jutschge You're still limiting the question.  The patch information doesn't need to be there at all.  You can mention she got a rework, but it's not like we want questions for each and every rework patch.  Thinking ahead, if she gets another rework, we don't need another question; we need to update the answers on this question.  That's why I removed it in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Telling what is the best role is a kind of difficult question. However her Kit is mainly built around supporting right now. She has More CC than before and also a higher healing rate (at the cost of her own HP). Soraka is even stronger in team fights than before simply because of her increased range on Q. Also her Ultimate got buffed a lot for more healing on targets below 50% HP. The AOE, Silence/Root also really boosts her team fighting potential.

So basically: You should play her as a full AP supporter. She will still be sort of viable in the mid lane, however her top viability is rather questionable since her potential lay in being an unstoppable pushing force top and she kind of lost her pushing power with her Q getting more Cooldown.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly the sort of answer i was looking for.

Comment: Also note that her W cannot be self-cast, and her passive requires a nearby low-health ally. So two of her five abilities are completely unavailable for solo laners (except during ganks).